# pyspark - how to add a column where value of new column is searched from the dataframe:

Tags: pyspark

how to add a column where value of new column is searched from the dataframe:

eg.

```
 A  B    newCol
 1  a     a
 2  b     null     
 3  c     null
 4  d     b
 5  e     null
 6  f     null
 7  g     null
 8  h     null
 9  i      c
```

The value in this case in newCol is based on sqrt of value in A. It is based on lookup in the current dataframe though not the same row.

pseudocode:

```
df[newCol] = df[sqrt(df[A])]
```

The sqr/sqrt is just an example - the lookup could be based on value in column B or something else. I added the sqrt example to eliminate the lead/lag answers. x

There may be no positional relationship between current element and what is being looked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `sqrt` which creates a float column, you can calculate square of column A and create a look up data frame from it and then merge it against the original data frame:

```py
lookup = df.withColumn('A', (df.A ** 2).cast('int')).withColumnRenamed('B', 'newCol')
df.join(lookup, on=['A'], how='left').show()
+---+---+------+
|  A|  B|newCol|
+---+---+------+
|  7|  g|  null|
|  6|  f|  null|
|  9|  i|     c|
|  5|  e|  null|
|  1|  a|     a|
|  3|  c|  null|
|  8|  h|  null|
|  2|  b|  null|
|  4|  d|     b|
+---+---+------+
```

Or without type casting:

```py
lookup = df.withColumn('A', df.A * df.A).withColumnRenamed('B', 'newCol')
df.join(lookup, on=['A'], how='left').show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but please don't focus on the sqrt part - this is not what I need -- I came up with that example, the lookup could can have different relation which is not really straightforward .. Updated the question to ignore the sqr/sqrt relation.

Comment: Can you edit your question to reflect the relation you are looking for?

Comment: Let me think about how to modify the question to have more independent lookup relation and also evaluate your answer. I was looking for something like df.query['value in A == value to find ']

Comment: I was able to get to the solution that I was looking for using your answer - accepting that as answer.